# App chrashes while changing view

Tags: android, xml

I want to create a very simple app. The app should consists of 2 views. In both views are one button. By clicking the button the view should change.

Here is my folder structure

[image: folder structur]

I have two activitys and two activity_layouts. As you can see `OverviewActivity` isn't inside the activity folder. When I place it into the folder I get this structur:

[image]

Why is the activity folder away? Can you give me a little explanation?

Ok, but in this question I use the first folder structur.

**activity_login.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="company.useradministration.activity.LoginActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="btnOverview"
        android:text="go to overview"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_overview.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".activity.OverviewActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="btnLogin"
        android:text="go to login"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**LoginActivity**

```html
package company.useradministration.activity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import company.useradministration.R;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    public void btnOverview(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
    }
}
```

**OverviewActivity**

```html
package company.useradministration.activity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import company.useradministration.R;

public class OverviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
    }

    public void btnLogin(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

Okay. When I start the app, I see a button with the text "go to view". After pressing this button, the view changed. Now I see a button with the text "go to overview". When I press this button, the app crashes with the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method btnOverview(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:307)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:266)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5085)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE:

**Here is the explained answer:**

You have a `activity_overview.xml` with it's class `OverviewActivity`.
In your `activity_overview.xml` you set the `android:onClick="btnLogin"` to the button and you have:

```
public void btnLogin(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
```

in your `OverviewActivity` so when user clicks this button it changes the contentview successfully. 
The question here is:

Why does the app crashes when you click on the button in `activity_login.xml` to change the contentview back to activity_overview.xml?

Simple. Because you have set the onclick method in your `LoginActivity` but you aren't switching to that activity but just changing the layout. So when the button to go back to overview content is clicked the app searches for the function in you `OverviewActivity` because the activity didn't swithed to `LoginActivity`. It has just changed the content and there is no function called `btnOverview` in your `OverviewActivity`. So here you have 2 solutions:
**1-** Create two `RelativeLayout`s in just one xml file and than `setVisibility` of each layouts on button click.
So for that you have to:

Create only one activity instead of two different and in it's xml file use this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/overview"
       android:visibility="gone">
       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:text="go to login"
           android:id="@+id/go_to_login"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    //Do your stuff here for overview content
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/login">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="go to overview"
            android:id="@+id/go_to_overview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   //Do your stuff here for login content
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This code has 2 `RelativeLayout`s. The first one with `id:overview` is of the overview content and it's visibility is gone and the second `RelativeLayout` with `id:login` has the visibility visible by default (Change the two layouts visibility as desired).

Than in your `MainActivty.java` (call it as you wish) you can change the visibility of these views like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button goToOverview, goToLogin;
RelativeLayout overview, login;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Remember to change the content to match your xml file name
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Buttons
    goToOverview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_overview);
    goToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_login);

    //Layouts
    overview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.overview);
    login = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.login);

    goToOverview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            login.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            overview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    goToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            overview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

In this way you can switch to two different layout without any problem.

**Edit:** You can achieve this also with this solution but the difference between the first solution and this solution is just that you will have 2 xml files instead of one.

**2nd-** You will have one java class file (in this example I will take `OverviewActivity`as example) and 2 different layout files (Which you already have: `activity_login.xml` and `activity_overview.xml`).

So in your `activity_overview.xml` change this line: `tools:context=".activity.OverviewActivity"` to `tools:context=".OverviewActivity"` as you said that you are using the first folder structure where the `OverviewActivity` file is out of the activity folder.
Than in your `OverviewActivity` make the following changes:

```
public class OverviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
}

public void btnLogin(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

public void btnOverview(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
}
}
```

That's it. Please comment if you are having any problem with the code. I will be glad to help your further more.
Hope this can solve your issue.
Regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now the button works, but it open a new window... I don't want a new window. How can I change the layout with activity without a new window?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edit! I have one more question. What is the better solution now?

Comment: For me the better between the two solution is the first one (visibility solution). But the fastest way is the second one. I think you should go with the first... And please accept my answer to help others find the right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
public void btnOverview(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
}
```

This changes the layout for the current activity `LoginActivity` to `activity_overview` which contains the button thats looking for the `btnLogin` method

You are successfully changing the layout, but your staying in the same activity, so the new layout is looking for a method that exists in the other activity

Instead change the above code to this:

```
public void btnOverview(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverviewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in `OverviewActivity`

```
public void btnLogin(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now the button works, but it open a new window... I don't want a new window. How can I change the layout with activity without a new window?

Comment: Just put the btnLogin method inside the LoginActivity class

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) as a help. I'm newbie myself to android java programming, but I believe you have to create **intent** to move to another activity. Additionally be sure to add your Activity to **AndroidManifest.xml**. That's all I think. If I'm wrong I'll be happy if someone more experienced will correct me :)

Comment: @MyNewName If you want new layout without opening new Activity try Layout Inflater

Comment: I agree with @Jakub Stasiak, the thing you want to do can be achieved by using Fragments in android.